# MySQL Server 5.7.11 working with MEB 4.0.3?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysql-5.7

Is it possible to create a backup with mysqlbackup.exe using the MEB 4.0.3 tool on MySQL 5.7.11?
For me it only worked with the 5.7.17 version. Am I supposed to use an older version of MEB in order to make it work?